# How to show/slide down a related radio button in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My question in title may not make sense but what I am trying to do is:

When I click text1's radio button, the subtext1's radio button will show up. Then when text2's radio buttonis clicked, subtext2's radio button will show up, meanwhile hiding subtext1's radio button and uncheck subtext1's radio button if it is checked before. Element id here is created in sequence from backend.

```
<form name="myForm">
    text1: <input type="radio" id="r1" name="myRadio"  value="1" onchange="action()"/>
      <div>subtext1: <input type="radio" id="r1" name="mysubRadio"  value="11" /></div>
    text2: <input type="radio" id="r2" name="myRadio"  value="2" onchange="action() />
      <div>subtext2: <input type="radio" id="r2" name="mysubRadio"  value="22" /></div> 
</form>
```

I try to use

```
document.getElementById('r1').getElementByName('myRadio')
```

to get specific radio button but it seems to be a bad syntax.

Anyone can provide a clue how I can know the sub radio button to show with related parent radio button I checked in javascript?

Comment: You forgot to post the JavaScript you tried.

Comment: You have jQuery tag, but are not using it.  Are you looking for both options?

Comment: Duplicate ID is invalid in a document: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2

Comment: For completeness, here is the HTML5 reference stating basically the same thing: http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute

Comment: @Mark Schultheiss , thanks for pointing that out. I can make the ID unique.

Answer (score 1):

Solution with jQuery:

```js
$(function() {
  var myRadios = $('input[name=myRadio]'); // cache all once
  var mysubRadios = $('input[name=mysubRadio]');
  myRadios.on('change', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); //cancel event bubbling
    myRadios.next('div').hide(); // hide all sub text
    mysubRadios.prop('checked', false); // un mark all sub radios
    $(this).next('div').show(); // show sub text for the current one
  });
  myRadios.next('div').hide(); // hide all sub text on page load
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="myForm">
  text1:
  <input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="1" />
  <div>subtext1:
    <input type="radio" name="mysubRadio" value="11" />
  </div>
  text2:
  <input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="2" />
  <div>subtext2:
    <input type="radio" name="mysubRadio" value="22" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Solution with plain js & css:

```js
var toggle = function() {
  var mysubRadio = document.getElementsByName('mysubRadio');
  var i = mysubRadio.length;
  var p;
  var el;
  var inp;
  while (i--) { // loop through each sub radios
    el = p = mysubRadio[i].parentNode; // get the parent div of radio
    while (el.previousSibling && !el.nodeName.match(/input/i)) { // get prev sibling input of the div
      el = el.previousSibling;
    }
    p.style.display = el.checked ? 'block' : 'none'; // show/hide sub text as per selection
    mysubRadio[i].checked = false; //un check
  }
};
```

```css
input[name=myRadio] + div {
  display: none;
  /* hide all sub text on page load */
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm">
  text1:
  <input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="1" onchange="toggle()" />
  <div>subtext1:
    <input type="radio" name="mysubRadio" value="11" />
  </div>
  text2:
  <input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="2" onchange="toggle()" />
  <div>subtext2:
    <input type="radio" name="mysubRadio" value="22" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Both solutions didn't use ids

**Edited: 10:04 AM (IST), 04th Aug 2015**

Solution with reference to [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yinyuantao/48qo6p55/1/)

```js
$(function() {
  var myRadios = $('input[name=myRadio]'); // cache all once
  var mysubRadios = $('input[name=mysubRadio]');
  myRadios.on('change', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); //cancel event bubbling
    myRadios.closest('tr').next('tr').hide(); // hide all sub text
    mysubRadios.prop('checked', false); // un mark all sub radios
    $(this).closest('tr').next('tr').show(); // show sub text for the current one
  });
  myRadios.closest('tr').next('tr').hide(); // hide all sub text on page load
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="myForm">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>text1:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" id="r1" name="myRadio" value="1" class="super" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <div class='subradio'>subtext1:
              <input type="radio" id="r2" name="mysubRadio" value="11" class='subradio' />
            </div>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>text2:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" id="r3" name="myRadio" value="2" class="super" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <div class='subradio'>subtext2:
              <input type="radio" id="r4" name="mysubRadio" value="22" class='subradio' />
            </div>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

**P.S.** Html elements must have unique ids

Comment: thanks, this is very nice. let me embed it into my jsp code.

Comment: one question, in real code, you mostly won't have <div> tag directly behind the parent <input> radio, also parent radio and sub radio may in different table, different <tr> or <td> tag. In that case, next() can't do the work.

Comment: Can you take a look http://jsfiddle.net/yinyuantao/48qo6p55/1/ see if you can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you cannot have multiple elements with the same id on the same page.  Remove the ids for the sub-radio buttons and add them to div as like id='r1a'/'r2a'  So ids for the sub radio buttons and you can do the following:

```
if (document.getElementById('r1').checked) {
    document.getElementById('r2').checked = false;
    document.getElementById('r2a').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('r1a').style.visibility = 'visible';
} else if (document.getElementById('r2').checked) {
    document.getElementById('r1').checked = false);
    document.getElementById('r2a').style.visibility = 'visible';
    document.getElementById('r1a').style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not have multiple ID's on single page, but if you must you can use querySelectorAll and do something like this:

Html:

```
<form name="myForm">
    text1:
    <input type="radio" id="r1" name="myRadio" value="1" onchange="MyAction(this.id)" />
    <div>
        subtext1:
        <input type="radio" id="r1" name="mysubRadio" value="11" />
    </div>
    text2:
    <input type="radio" id="r2" name="myRadio" value="2" onchange="MyAction(this.id)" />
      <div>subtext2: 
<input type="radio" id="r2" name="mysubRadio"  value="22" />
</div> 
</form>
```

JS:

```
function MyAction(id) {
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll("#"+id);
    for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if (elements[i].getAttribute("name") == "mysubRadio") {
            elements[i].parentNode.style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
    }
}
```

[fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/k3m0ewpw/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you can do this simply if you add classes to the parents and sub radios:

```
<form name="myForm">text1:
    <input type="radio" id="r1" name="myRadio" value="1" class="super" />
    <div class='subradio'>subtext1:
        <input type="radio" id="r2" name="mysubRadio" value="11" class='subradio' />
    </div>text2:
    <input type="radio" id="r3" name="myRadio" value="2" class="super" />
    <div class='subradio'>subtext2:
        <input type="radio" id="r4" name="mysubRadio" value="22" class='subradio' />
    </div>
</form>


$('.super').on('change', function () {
    $('div.subradio').hide();
    $(this).next('.subradio').show().find('input.subradio').prop('checked', true);
});
```

NOTE: no need to "uncheck" since the radios have the same name property when you check one, the other(s) get unchecked.

Sample of the working code here: http://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/jy807kgo/

Comment: thx, and i think we should use nextAll().first() to get next matching tag since in real world the parent and sub radio won't be stick together.

Comment: This solution works for the markup you provided as a part of your question.  Perhaps a new question would be in order if it differs that much from what you have posted.

Comment: Can you take a look http://jsfiddle.net/yinyuantao/48qo6p55/1/ ? In my case, using next, nextAll.first, parent seems to be not working. Does jquery provide any other method to search a tag? And In your example the code will break once HTML DOM structure get updated